# Product not updating - Mongoose MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am unable to update and save a change in the database using mongoose. I am getting the same value for `foundProduct` twice when I console.log. What could be going wrong?

```
// Schema
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        onSale: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false,
        },
    }
)

// model
const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)

const findProduct = async () => {
    const foundProduct = await Product.findOne({ name: 'Mountain Bike' });
    console.log(foundProduct)
    foundProduct.OnSale = true;
    await foundProduct.save().then((data) => console.log(data))
    // console.log(foundProduct)
}

findProduct();
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the value of OnSale for the product that you queried?

Comment: simply `findProduct().then(() => {})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. Change `foundProduct.OnSale = true;` with `foundProduct.onSale = true;`.

Since you are using the wrong case, Mongoose considers OnSale to be an extra field. And because it's not in your schema, it's ignored when saving to db.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo error in the `foundProduct.OnSale` instead of `foundProduct.onSale`